# Doctrine and Zend_Form Validation

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, doctrine

I am using Zend Framework and Doctrine on a project and was wondering if anyone can suggest a good way to integrate Doctrine's validation with Zend_Form. I'm trying to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with aggregating the errors for your form you can do it in the following way:
 - Make a Zend_Form without validators
 - On submit, make a Doctrine object and call isValid()
 - If not valid, don't store, but show form again with an error

What I would recommend you however, is to either
 - Write both the validators for your Zend_Form and your model. 
 - Write Validators for your Zend_Form that take a Doctrine Model and field as input and then validate the stuff against your model

I suppose the latter option could be a very generic library, useful for even inclusion into the Zend Framework. It is however tedious to write it in the right way.

Comment: I've been trying something similar to your isValid() suggestion, only I'm doing it in a custom Zend_Form class that stores an instance of the Doctrine model being validated against:

    public function isValid($data) {
        $this->getModel()
             ->fromArray($this->getValues());
        if (!$model->isValid()) {
            ...
        }

I hadn't thought about creating custom validators, I'll look into doing it that way as well, thanks for the suggestion.